# Angular2: Find out if FormControl has required validator?

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, validation

does someone know a way to find out for an Angular2 FormControl if the required validor is registered for the control.

```
this.form = builder.group({name: ['', Validators.required]};
```

Can I then query the `this.form.controls['name']` control if it is a required field? I know I can check if it is valid, but that's not what I want.

Kind regards,
Marc

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @marc did you find a solution? Closest I've got is by using the "getError()" method of the AbstractControl or FormControl, but it's populated too late in the lifecycle.

Comment: i also need some solution for this case. (know if a form field is required without validate, just know if is required, with value or without value), did you find a solution?

Answer (score 76):

This function should work for FormGroups and FormControls

```
  export const hasRequiredField = (abstractControl: AbstractControl): boolean => {
    if (abstractControl.validator) {
        const validator = abstractControl.validator({}as AbstractControl);
        if (validator && validator.required) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (abstractControl['controls']) {
        for (const controlName in abstractControl['controls']) {
            if (abstractControl['controls'][controlName]) {
                if (hasRequiredField(abstractControl['controls'][controlName])) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: I was confused by the 3rd line until I looked at it again today.  So the validator function is exposed and can be called on any control; you're calling it on an empty object masquerading as a control.  Got it.  My question: why does this only work for the required validator?  I tried this on a field with solely a minLength validator and the resulting object was empty.  Can this trick be used to check for anything other than required?

Comment: It only worked for the required-validator in this Angular version, thought it was v4. Noticed the same thing like you.

Comment: @MarcelTinner - Here is a gist of how to implement your solution with good performance: https://gist.github.com/jsdevtom/5589af349a395b37e699b67417ef025b

Comment: abstractControl.validator is not a function for AbstractControl type , how it will work

Comment: why do you return `false` instead of `null` ?

Comment: @Tom It seems that the hash changes between two validations when there are multiple validators... Did you run into this issue ? I saw that your tests do not include multiple validators in the gist.

Answer (score 25):

Angular now provides [`hasValidator`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasValidator) with which you can check if a formcontrol has a sync validator. If you happen to need to check if it has an async validator, that also exist with [`hasAsyncValidator`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasasyncvalidator).

In your case when you want to check if the formcontrol is required, you can do:

```
this.form.get('name').hasValidator(Validators.required);
```

EDIT: TypeScript now usually complains about

> `"Property 'hasValidator' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'`

You need to tell TypeScript that this is actually a `FormControl` (not "only" the baseclass `AbstractControl`). So for example the following should work fine:

```
(this.form.get('name') as FormControl).hasValidator(Validators.required);
```

Comment: this gives an error "Property 'hasValidator' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.". this method might be depracated

Comment: hasValidator() only exists for angular 12

Comment: @chitgoks That is not correct, there is a link in my answer to the documentation, where it is still present to this day. "hasValidator" does exist :)

Comment: @AT82 i forgot what the my version is (i think 10) but it doesnt exist. really.

Answer (score 16):

While there is no Angular API to directly find if the `required` validator is set for a particular field, the roundabout way to achieve this is like as below:

```
import { NgForm, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

const isRequiredControl = (formGroup: NgForm, controlName: string): boolean => {
    const { controls } = formGroup
    const control = controls[controlName]
    const { validator } = control
    if (validator) {
        const validation = validator(new FormControl())
        return validation !== null && validation.required === true
    }
    return false
}
```

I have tested this and this triggers only if the `Validator.Required` validator is added to the particular `FormControl`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no method how to check validators or get all validators: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

@fairlie-agile solution is pretty clever. But I think we have to use empty FormControl because we need fire required validator and  `this.group.controls[this.config.name]` could be already initialized with some value.

```
ngOnInit() {
    let formControl = this.group.controls[this.config.name];
    let errors: any = formControl.validator && formControl.validator(new FormControl());
    this._required = errors !== null && errors.required;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue. For now, I'm using this:

```
  import { Attribute } from '@angular/core';

  // "Kind-of" hack to allow "pass-through" of the required attribute
  constructor(@Attribute('required') public required) {
    // call super here if the component is an ancestor
  }
```

I'm really puzzled as to why properties like "disabled" are included in FormControl, but not "required".

Comment: because require yields no special meaning in the forms API, its just like any possible error. If you were to make a special validator that populates the `error` property `notABanana` you wouldn't want that on the AC would you? I do think we need  way to access the current validators on a given AC though.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to check if the control is valid when the form is loaded to see if it has the required error (which it will if the field is empty).

This won't work for other validators, such as minLength, as they are not fired until the control is changed

```
export class FormInputComponent implements Field, OnInit {
  private _required: boolean;
  config: FieldConfig;
  group: FormGroup;

    /** Readonly properties. */
  get required(): boolean { 
    return this._required;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var _validator: any = this.group.controls[this.config.name].validator && this.group.controls[this.config.name].validator(this.group.controls[this.config.name]);
    this._required = _validator && _validator.required;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a very good solution, since an input could be populated with a value on init.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem with this:

```
get lastPriceField(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.get('last_price');
}

private checkIfFieldHasValidatorRequired() {    
    const validators = (this.lastPriceField as any)._rawValidators;
    this._lastPriceIsRequired = validators && validators.some(item => item.name === "required");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that the only error registered initially is the `required` error

```js
// in your component you'll have access to `this.myFormGroup`
const formGroup = {
  controls: {
    email: {
      errors: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    username: {
      errors: null
    }    
  }
}

// required by default
let required = {
  email: '*',
  username: '*',
};

// in `ngOnInit`
required = Object.entries(formGroup.controls)
  .map(([key, control]) => [key, control.errors])
  .filter(([, errors]) => !errors)
  .map(([key]) => [key, ''])
  .reduce((_required, [key, isRequired]) => Object.assign(_required, { [key]: isRequired }), required)

// in your template you may write `<label>Email{{ required.email }}</label>`
console.log(required)
```

Answer (score 0):

A short version.
First, create an empty control to avoid doing it constantly in the method.

```
  private readonly emptyFormControl = new FormControl();
```

Then check in the method. A control is mandatory if it's enabled and its validator gains an 'required' error when validating an empty control.

```
  private isMandatory = (fc: FormControl): boolean =>
    fc.enabled && !!fc.validator && !!fc.validator(this.emptyFormControl)?.required;
```

This is only applicable to the FormControl object. If you need to support FormGroup or / and FormArray, you need to add recursion to the checking method.

Answer (score -4):

I don't know what's the exact way is to check if control has required validator or not.

But workaround could be this,
Whenever control has required validator, it adds **validator()** function to that control.

eg.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="firstname">

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstname: ['', Validators.required]     //<<<===one required validation on firstname control
    });

    console.log(this.registerForm.controls.firstname.validator.length);
                                                 //<<<===this will return 1.
   });
```

}

In above code, length of validator is one(1)

---

```
  console.log(this.registerForm.controls.firstname.validator.length);
                                                 //this will return exception
```

this line will return one. If no validator is attached then firstname will not have validator() function so in that case I'll give an exception.

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/I7b5JNAavmCJ6Py1eQRr?p=preview**

Comment: This will only tell you if there's a validator present, not if it's the required validator specifically, which is what OP asked.