# Inspect a FormControl's validators programmatically

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a custom `FormFieldComponent` that encapsulates the HTML and error display logic for each form field.

Basically, my forms look like this (`field` is the selector for my custom component):

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <field label="Title" [control]="myForm.get('title')">
    <input type="text" formControlName="title">
  </field>
  <field label="Description" [control]="myForm.get('description')">
    <textarea formControlName="description"></textarea>
  </field>
  ...
</form>
```

Inside my `FormFieldComponent`, I'd like to inspect the FormControl's validators programmatically to customize the component's display, such as:

- Add a little * when the field is required.
- Customize the help text message based on the validators (e.g. "10 characters max").
- ...

The only property of interest is `FormControl.validator` but it contains the validation function for all the validators associated to the field. Not very convenient.

Is there any other way to inspect a FormControl's validators?

Note. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819123/angular2-find-out-if-formcontrol-has-required-validator) is identical, but I thought I'd ask again with a different wording. :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware you'd have to parse out the validator function.