# Checking for a pattern validator on a FormGroup

Tags: angular

I have an input that has its validators change depending on a previously selected field above.

I would like to test this, so I need to be able to specify a selected field and then confirm if the respective validator has been applied/added to the `input`. Checking for a `required` validator is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819123/angular2-find-out-if-formcontrol-has-required-validator), however I cannot find anything for a `pattern` validator.

How do I check if a `pattern` validator has been applied to a given `input` on a `FormGroup`?

**Edit:**
The adding of the `pattern` validator is done dynamically based on the value of another `input` within the same `FormGroup` via an `onSelectionChange` method.

Angular version is 7.2.2

Comment: have you tried .pattern in the place of .required in the first answer of that stack overflow question?

Comment: Thanks @RomyGomez. Yeah I did try but Angular 7 doesn't seems to have the property `validator.pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have declared something like below,

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  email:  new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
  ]));
});
```

then, you can test if it is valid like below

```
if(this.form.controls['email'].valid) {
  console.log("email is valid");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be testing the validity of the `pattern` rather than whether or not the `pattern` has been applied to the `input` although there is an underlying implication. Its possible that a missing `pattern` would still trigger a `valid` state on the `input` making the test invalid

Comment: @Luke, Can you please explain what you meant by 'pattern has been applied to the input'. Do you mean that the user has entered a pattern or not?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was adding the `pattern` validator to the list of validators on the input e.g.`control.setValidators(Validators.pattern('^$'));`

Comment: @Luke, So, if you see my answer, you have the validators for required and pattern as well. Do you want to add the pattern validator dynamically?

Comment: Yeah the `pattern` validator will be added dynamically based on the value of another `input` within the same `FormGroup` done with a `onSelectionChange` method.