# Get validators type from CustomForm Component

Tags: angular, validation, controlvalueaccessor

I'm using Angular 7, I created a customForm Component (called `app-lav-input`), i.e. a component that inherits from `ControlValueAccessor`.

This is how I use `app-lav-input`:

HTML:

```
      <app-lav-input
        [label]="'name"
        formControlName="reference">
      </app-lav-input>
```

Component's code:

```
    this.basicDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      reference: ['', [ Validators.required ] ], ] ],
    });
```

I would like to add a '*' in `app-lav-input` template if `Validators.required` is used.

I could add another input to `app-lav-input` but it would be much nicer to get this information from the formControl.

How can I access this information from `app-lav-input` component's code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if a form control has a required validator as shown here: [Angular2: Find out if FormControl has required validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010307/1164465)

Comment: Indeed, it is, I was missing `{}as AbstractControl` in `abstractControl.validator({}as AbstractControl)`