# How to get validation rule FormControl?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive control like this:

```js
rootDocumentType: new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
```

I want to check if this field has `required` rule and then display a star in the template like this:

```html
<span *ngIf = "form.controls.rootDocumentType.validator.required">*</span>
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819123/angular2-find-out-if-formcontrol-has-required-validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom `isRequired` method and pass each control to get the validation status either is has validation or not.

Template:

```
<span *ngIf="isRequired(form.get('rootDocumentType'))">*</span>
```

In component

**NOTE:** [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors) always have an Object if you notice I used `!!` to make it boolean.

```
 isRequired(control: AbstractControl) {
   return control.validator ? !!control.validator(control) : false;
 }
```